# How can I change the password policy in a JHipster app?

Tags: jhipster

For the app types that handle user management (JWT, Session), how can I change the password policy to meet my specific needs?

The only common point where it would make sense to add password validation logic is in `AccountResource#checkPasswordLength(String password)`

```
private static boolean checkPasswordLength(String password) {
    return !StringUtils.isEmpty(password) &&
        password.length() >= ManagedUserVM.PASSWORD_MIN_LENGTH &&
        password.length() <= ManagedUserVM.PASSWORD_MAX_LENGTH;
}
```

But this definitely does not seem like the correct place to do it.